# How to redirect GET with dynamic route from Program.cs to a custom controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to reach my controller and action with a dynamic url that looks like this:

```
// http://127.0.0.1:4567/api/img/get/stuff/1/0/45/strings/numbers/andallkindsofstuff/2
```

Only "api/img/get" are static for my custom controller, the rest is dynamic and contains all kinds of parameters for the resource. So how can I make the middleware route all GET requests that start with "api/img/get" to my controller and action? Controller and action generate images and return them.

Below is some code from my entry point Program.cs. I would actually prefer to be able to parse path and call the corresponding controller from the code below, because routing does not seem to work with dynamic routes.

```
// business logic code removed
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!MyCache.Ready) return; // ignores requests just fine

    // new CustomController().Get(content.Request.Path)

    await next(); // calls controllers
});
app.UseMvc();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();

// controller:
[Route("api/img")]
[ApiController]
public class ImageController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("get")]
    public byte[] Get([FromQuery] string parameters)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your controller and action defination as well? I am trying to reproducee the issue your shared snippet.

Comment: I have gone though your code snippet and trying to investigate what you are trying to achieve, since you cannot modify dynamic route as its a type of `get` only allow to extract the value. Thus, we can  use wildcard search in our route to match any kind of route parameter.

Comment: Therefore, in your route you can set `[Route("get/{**parameters}")]` and then `public byte[] Get([FromQuery] string parameters)` which will allow you to extract all value and you can set your logic inside your controller. Please [`have a look on this official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-templates).